# In EFCore, how do I scaffold my context and then start doing migrations?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I want to do code first development on an existing SQL Server Database. I have used the Scaffold-DbContext command to generate the entities that I want into the tables I want. That's great. But, there were previously code first migrations done to this database. So I deleted the __EFMigrationsHistory table in the SQL Database. Now I want to start doing migrations. Unfortunately, when I run Add-Migration, it generates migration code to generate all of the tables again. I don't understand how I am supposed to tell it that these tables already exist. When I am reverse engineering, how do I generate the migration of the stuff it's scaffolding for me in the existing database?

Comment: _So I deleted the __EFMigrationsHistory table in the SQL Database_. - By doing so, basically you are telling EF that there are no migrations applied. So it tries to do them again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Code First Migrations uses a snapshot of the model stored in the most recent migration to detect changes to the model (you can find detailed information about this in Code First Migrations in Team Environments).

Source [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/existing-database).

Run `Add-Migration InitialCreate –IgnoreChanges` to create the initial migration from an existing database. Then `update-database` to simply add the migration to the _EFMigrationsHistory table.

After that, you are good to go brother.